# Active Directory Security Identifier

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, sid

What is meant by an "Identifier Authority" in the SID in Active Directory?  In an object's SID in my domain controller denotes 5 which is an NT-Authority.  So what actually meant by the Identifier Authority and what it points to?

Answer (score 1):

This value identifies the highest level of authority that can issue SIDs for this particular type of security principal. Another way of saying this is that the Identifier value identifies the authority that issued the SID

This article explains the Identifier Authority values

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd302645.aspx

check out this article it explains the SID structure

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962011.aspx

There is also this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379597(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps, if you are happy can you mark my answer as correct please.